# How to Navigate the Robot using RTABmapViz

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using rtabmap_ros package to simulate 3D mapping and navigation of the mobile Robot. As for the first part, I can generate the 3D map of the environment simulated in gazebo. However, when I run my rtabmap source file in localization mode it loads the 3D map successfully but does not show the robot model as it does in RVIZ. Please note that I run my gazebo model before running rtabmap launch file.

1. Can I connect gazebo and rtabmap so that robot model shows in rtabmap interface?
2. how can I send commands to robot in localization mode using rtabmap and print its trajectory? (Please note that I am aware of send goal command using node ID in rtabmap interface but it does not seem to work as there is no robot model in the rtabmap interface)
3. Is it possible to connect RVIZ and rtabmap so that robot model shows in both (rtabmap and RVIZ) interfaces and when given the 2D navigation command in RVIZ, robot also moves in rtabmap? Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329494/how-to-navigate-the-robot-using-rtabmapviz/) by [al389660](https://answers.ros.org/users/38821/al389660/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. No, use [RobotModel](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/RobotModel) display in RVIZ instead
2. `/rtabmap/goal` should be connected to `/move_base_simple/goal`, or rtabmap is configured to use actionlibs with move_base like in this [example](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/azimut3/az3_nav.launch):

`

```
 <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen">
  <param name="use_action_for_goal" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <remap from="move_base" to="/move_base"/>
 </node>
```

3. We cannot add 3D models for visualization in rtabmapviz. However, if the robot moves, the referential corresponding to `base_link` frame will move in rtabmapviz.

Note that rtabmapviz is used only for visualization (not required for SLAM), so in general we choose between rviz or rtabmapviz. We can open both too: rtabmapviz used to monitor loop closures and see statistics, while rviz is used to show the map and the robot model.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0